# lambda returns blank payload in response

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am invoking the lambda function like

```
let settings = {
    'FunctionName': 'foo'
}
setTimeout(() => {
    lambda.invoke(settings, (err, response) => {  });
}
```

`response.StatusCode` is `200`, but when I check `response.Payload`, it's always blank.

My lambda function is having only `context.succeed("Hello")`

Used `aws-sdk` npm

Comment: I'm assuming you used `lambda.invoke` instead of using an HTTP request. Why are you getting `StatusCode` when your Lambda is only returning a `Hello` string? It seems like your question is incomplete.

Comment: Please check if you've used any intercepter for the requests.